# Best Approach To Run 2 Scripts Inside Looping Sequentially

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm new in Unix/Gnu/Linux and trying learn some more about it.

I have a case where I need to run 2 scripts inside a loop, but these 2 scripts need to run sequentially.

For example:

```
TargetFile = /data/TEST.CSV

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];
do
   script_copy_file.sh $Parm1 $Parm2 $Parm3
   script_split_file.sh $Parm1 $Parm2   
done < "$TargetFile"
```

Do I need to put something in between those 2 scripts so the script_split_file.sh will run after script_copy_file is finished?
I read some article to use &&, but I'm here to seek some advice about the best practice for it.

Or will it naturally run in sequence?

Sorry if my question is funny or weird, I just try to learn and understand.
Really appreciate for your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The two scripts will run one after the other if you invoke them on separate lines in a script, without anything but a newline between them, like you're showing in the question.

You only want to put `&&` between them if you want the second script to *only* run if the first script end successfully.

With a newline (or `;`) between the invocations, the second script will run regardless of whether the first script ran successfully or not.

Using `||` between them will make the second script run only if the first script fails (returns a non-zero exit status).

Looking at your code, you will also want to double-quote your paramaeter expansions:

```bsh
script_copy_file.sh "$Parm1" "$Parm2" "$Parm3"
script_split_file.sh "$Parm1" "$Parm2"
```

... and assignments should have no spaces around the `=`.

Related:

- [How to run multiple scripts one after another but only after previous one got completed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552695/how-to-run-multiple-scripts-one-after-another-but-only-after-previous-one-got-co)
- [And Operator and Semi Colon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586171/and-operator-and-semi-colon)

Answer (score 0):

## It will run:

```
script_copy_file.sh
script_split_file.sh

script_copy_file.sh
script_split_file.sh

script_copy_file.sh
script_split_file.sh
…
```

## If you want it to run

```
script_copy_file.sh
script_copy_file.sh
script_copy_file.sh

script_split_file.sh
script_split_file.sh
script_split_file.sh
```

Then you need two loops.

## Other

You need to quote variables, consider are you using the correct variables, not have a space before the `=` in the assignment, and use `shellcheck` to check your scripts.

Use of `.sh` at the end of file-names is also a bad idea, it will cause problems maybe not to day, maybe not tomorrow, but someday. Imagine how may scripts you will have to rewrite when you re-implement one of your scripts in python.